# Reading unstructured dictionaries in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe from a collection of dictionaries that I read from a json file. The dictionaries are as follows -

```
d1 = {"DisplayName": "Test_drive", "permissions": {"read": True, "read_acp": True, "write": True, "write_acp": True}}
d2= {"DisplayName": "Log delivery","URI": "http://test_drive.com/Logs", "permissions": {"read": False, "read_acp": True, "write": True, "write_acp": False}}
```

I am trying to get these into a pandas dataframe. When I try to read them in a dataframe like following -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d) **or** df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

it generates this -

```
                DisplayName  permissions
read       Test_drive         True
read_acp   Test_drive         True
write      Test_drive         True
write_acp  Test_drive         True
```

or read it as following -

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d).Transpose()
```

it generates this -

```
                         read          read_acp             write         write_acp
DisplayName  Test_drive  Test_drive  Test_drive  Test_drive
permissions              True              True              True              True
```

I am trying to read these dictionaries and join them into one dataframe -

```
**DisplayName**              **read**          **read_acp**             **write**         **write_acp**         URI
Test_drive         True              True              True              True         NA
Log delivery            False             True              True             False         http://test_drive.com/Logs
```

Is there any pytonic way to do this?

Comment: `AWSAUDPL203027QA` is in your desired output but not in your input d1 or d2. where does that come from? are you sure your desired output matches the input d1/d2 you listed?

Comment: @MaxPower - Fixed the data frames to reflect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Vishnudev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5120049/vishnudev) and [Max Power](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870832/max-power) for your help. I think the following answer gives me the exact dataframe that I was trying to get.

```
d1 = {"DisplayName": "Test_drive", "permissions": {"read": True, "read_acp": True, "write": True, "write_acp": True}}
d2= {"DisplayName": "Log delivery","URI": "http://test_drive.com/Logs", "permissions": {"read": False, "read_acp": True, "write": True, "write_acp": False}}
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(d1),pd.Series(d2)], axis=1).transpose()
df = pd.concat([df.drop(['permissions'], axis=1),df['permissions'].apply(pd.Series)],axis=1)

**DisplayName                         URI   read  read_acp  write  write_acp**
0    Test_drive                         NaN   True      True   True       True
1  Log delivery  http://test_drive.com/Logs  False      True   True      False
```

Answer (score 2):

Create dataframe by appending and then reshape to the structure you need using pivot

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1).append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d2))
df.reset_index().pivot(index='DisplayName', columns='index', values='permissions')
```

To include URI

```
>>> df.reset_index().pivot(index='DisplayName', columns='index', values=['permissions', 'URI'])
             permissions                                                  URI                                                                                    
index               read read_acp write write_acp                        read                    read_acp                       write                   write_acp
DisplayName                                                                                                                                                      
Log delivery       False     True  True     False  http://test_drive.com/Logs  http://test_drive.com/Logs  http://test_drive.com/Logs  http://test_drive.com/Logs
Test_drive          True     True  True      True                         NaN                         NaN                         NaN                         NaN
```

Comment: @Vishnudev- This drops one of the columns called URL while doing this.

Comment: @Steve_Greenwood: this is a great answer (now updated to address your comment). including both columns to transpose in the `values` param of pivot is much better than my answer of transposing and merging. I suggest you accept this answer (click the green check to the left of it)

Comment: The answer is good but it creates more columns 'URI' which are needed to be dropped. 
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(d1),pd.Series(d2)], axis=1).transpose()
df = pd.concat([df.drop(['permissions'], axis=1),df['permissions'].apply(pd.Series)],axis=1)

Comment: @Steve_Greenwood you have  "URI" column in your question's desired output

Comment: @MaxPower : True but the pivot actually is creating 4 columns for URI. The "http://test_drive.com/Logs" is being repeated 4 times under sub-headings - read,                    read_acp, write and write_acp in the answer above as well as when I am trying to do that.

Comment: My answer was generic, considering the fact that the URI can be different for  different permission.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# Input Data
d1 = {"DisplayName": "Test_drive", "permissions": {"read": True, "read_acp": True, "write": True, "write_acp": True}}
d2= {"DisplayName": "Log delivery","URI": "http://test_drive.com/Logs", "permissions": {"read": False, "read_acp": True, "write": True, "write_acp": False}}

# Convert to DataFrame
dicts = [d1, d2]
df_rows = [pd.DataFrame(d) for d in dicts]
df = pd.concat(df_rows, axis=0).reset_index(drop=False)

# Reshape As Desired
tp1 = df.pivot(index='DisplayName', columns='index', values='permissions')
answer = tp1.merge(df[['DisplayName', 'URI']].drop_duplicates(), 
                   how='left', 
                   left_index=True, 
                   right_on='DisplayName').set_index('DisplayName')
```

Output:

```
>>> answer
               read  read_acp  write  write_acp                         URI
DisplayName                                                                
Log delivery  False      True   True      False  http://test_drive.com/Logs
Test_drive     True      True   True       True                         NaN
```